# What database to use for a clicks stream application RELATIONAL OR NOSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, nosql, key-value-store

I need to create a database for dealing with click stream (from ~240 subdomains). I use a Java Script for grabbing information like (Host, Page, Date, userID, Referer, HostName, RefererPath, uniqueUserID) for each click and than insert the data to the database through a java web dynamic application. There are about 9 milion new records each day and I have to insert new records every minute. Another application needs to be able to retrieve information about  pageviews/unique visitors/ect for a certain article/subdomain in the last (10min, 20min, 30min, 1hour...24 hours). I only need to keep records for the last 3 months.

Initially I thought about using MySQL as I'm only interested in open-source. But I'm thinking about NoSQL solutions. The problem is that I've had experience only with relational databases and am not really able to tell if NoSQL would be a better solution here or not. Also which database should I use if I choose to go wiht NoSQL? and would Key-value store be the best way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this data consistency isn't critical (statistics ?) so you could indeed spare a bit of consistency. NoSQL seems a good choice and a key value store would also be my pick. Now the real question is : what is the most suited one ?

I'd give a consideration to Redis and Riak (which are basically the most well-known ones) :

**Riak** (AP system) :

- Fault-tolerant (masterless with partitioning and replication)
- [Map reduce](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEoQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce&ei=TIDdUci3DNKChQf5m4DgCw&usg=AFQjCNEFv8pzQz4x8PZOV3V1dPH_SmC7DA&sig2=_BwKH8oVyHL-It7fUoCgmA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZG4)
- Full text search
- [BASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342497/explanation-of-base-terminology?lq=1)

**Redis** (CP system) :

- Really fast
- In-memory : You need RAM ! That also means you want replication so you don't lose everything on a crash. Redis also uses disk snapshot I believe.
- Master/Slave with [reelection](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel)
- BASE

Both have a lot more features, you should go read the documentation for gotchas. Redis is primarly used as a cache since it's fast, whereas Riak focuses on fault-tolerance. Given your scalability requirements, both can satisfy your need. Therefore you must chose according to what's above.

Comment: thanks a lot :) consistency isn't critical I also don't need any primary or foreign keys